# How can I install mod_bw for Apache in Oracle Linux 9?

Tags: software-installation, apache-httpd, repository, oracle-linux

I tried to install mod_bw for Apache web server in Oracle Linux 9,
but without success. 
The problem is that I am already using the EPEL repository
for Enterprise Linux 9. I tried this:

```
yum install mod_bw
```

And I got this error message:

```
No match for argument: mod_bw
Error: Unable to find a match: mod_bw
```

Are there any other repositories that may contain mod_bw?

Comment: You are allowed to post a question on Stack Exchange and [a non-Stack Exchange site](https://www.solveforum.com/forums/threads/how-can-i-install-mod_bw-for-apache-in-oracle-linux-9.2269721/) simultaneously,  but it’s common courtesy to ***tell us**,* so people can look to see whether the question has been answered on the other site before they put any effort into answering it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fedora 35, 36, and 37 have it in the `fedora` repository but for RHEL, Oracle, Alma Linux, and Rocky Linux:

1. Add the `raven-modular` repo:

Keep in mind that ithis is a third party repo and it will install dependencies including different releases of the following packages from the raven-modular repository that won't be supported instead of the releases from the Oracle Linux repository.

```
httpd
httpd-filesystem
httpd-tools
```

https://pkgs.dyn.su/el9/base/x86_64/raven-release-1.0-4.el9.noarch.rpm

Install the rpm and enable the repo with either of the following:

A)

```
dnf config-manager --enable raven-modular`
```

B)

```
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable mod_bw
```

Last, install the package:

```
yum install mod_bw
```

2. 

Get it from the source code via Apache. Here are the instructions for acquiring, compiling, and enabling it. Keep in mind that it hasn't been updated in quite some time and it may be difficult to compile and get it to work if at all.

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/sandbox/mod_bw/mod_bw.txt

The first method is more convenient and will actually get it onto the system whereas the second method won't install other packages from an unsupported repository but may be more difficult.